# conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>

Tags: c++

I have a stack of pairs in a `spreadsheet` obj:

```
std::stack< std::pair<std::string, std::string> > undoStack;
```

And I am trying to pop the stack and assign it to another pair:

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> change = spreadsheets.at(i).undoStack.pop();
```

And I am getting this error:

```
error: conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘std::pair<std::basic_string<char,   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’ requested
```

Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`stack::pop()` returns void but you are attempting to assign it to a variable. You need to call `top()` in order to retrieve the element before you pop it off the stack.

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> change = spreadsheets.at(i).undoStack.top();
spreadsheets.at(i).undoStack.pop();
```

You should look at the documentation for [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) to get familiar with it's member functions and use.

[documentation for `std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)

Comment: Ah perfect. I figured the `pop` worked the same as in c# or java.

Comment: I included a link to the documentation of stack. The entire site is a great reference for C++ and the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pop()` function of the stack returns `void`. you have type mismatch.

You should call `undoStack.top()` instead.